# How can I disable specific context menu items for a specific folder?

Tags: c#, contextmenu, windows-explorer

How can I disable specific context menu items for a specific folder in explorer?

For example for a directory `"C:\a"` I want to disable the options:
"send to", `"cut"`, `"copy"` on right `click`,
but only for this specific folder, other folders will have all the options enabled.